# Are there $r$ pairwise edge-disjoint $k$-sets of internally disjoint $s$-$t$-paths? Complexity

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs, np-hard, path

Given an undirected graph, two vertices $s$ and $t$, and two integers $k$ and $r$, then a $k$-set of internally disjoint $s$-$t$-paths is defined to be a set of exactly $k$ $s$-$t$-paths that share no vertex except for $s$ and $t$. What is the complexity of deciding whether there are $r$ pairwise edge-disjoint $k$-sets of internally disjoint $s$-$t$-paths?

It is obviously in $\mathsf{NP}$, but i can neither find a reduction to show $\mathsf{NP}$-hardness, nor a polynomial algorithm.

Comment: What about if you simplify your problem in some obvious ways (that is, let $k$ be one, two, etc.)? What do you know about the complexity then?

Comment: So what i have found out: If $k$ is one, we can solve the problem in polynomial time by Menger's Theorem, because we can compute the maximum number of edge-disjoint $s$-$t$-paths in $G$. For $k=2$ i'm not so sure. If we however have a given set of paths, or a given set of (more than one) vertex pairs that the paths must connect, and we should check how many of these paths have the desired property, then the problem is $NP$-complete.